# Can I save a cloned element to the localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to save a cloned element to the localStorage, so that I can append it afterwords from it. Unfortunately, I get an error when I attach it:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="elem"></div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let storageArr = [];

  storageArr.push({
    elem: $("#elem").clone()
  });

  localStorage.setItem("customStorageKey", JSON.stringify(storageArr));

  let storage = localStorage.getItem("customStorageKey"),
    parsedStorage = JSON.parse(storage);

  $(parsedStorage).each(function(index, elem) {
    $("#wrapper").append(elem["elem"]);
  });
});
```

```css
#elem {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

So is it possible to save a cloned HTML element to the localStorage?

Comment: Local storage holds strings, you can't save elements there.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the info. Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: You are stringifying the whole array, then treating the parsed object as one element. Does using `parsedStorage = JSON.parse(storage)[0]` help?

Comment: Store a serialised data structure, such as JSON, which holds the information about the element which you can use to recreate it the next time the page loads

Comment: @AnisR. Nope. I'm looping over it because it can take multiple items in the future.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So there is now way to save the whole element structure? Because it can have optional data tags which makes this think really complex.

Comment: You could fudge some code together to do that, but it's really not a good idea. Note that you can get all `data` tags as an object using jQuery's `data()` (with no arguments) which makes the job of serialising them a one-liner

Comment: you can store html of element in localStorage, but it might be security issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thats an idea. Is there a fast and easy way to print out all data attributes in my loop?